# How to make Charles Proxy listen on specific ip on a windows 10 laptop with multiple ipaddresses

Tags: android, charles-proxy

I am on windows 10 laptop which has two network interfaces (10.* and 192.*)( one assigned by the router and another by a VPN virtual adapter).  When I start Charles Proxy, it by default starts listening on the 10*.* interface. Is there a way I can make it listen on the 192. interface`?

Following is the screenshot of the issue I am facing. Without Charles Proxy listening on the 192.* `ip`, I cannot get my Android devices to proxy via the Charles despite adding the required Proxy settings on the Android device.

[image]

Comment: Did you Configure your phone to that ip address 10*. wifi or mobile network.

Comment: the phone cannot be configured to 10.* it automatically picks up the address from the wifi router which giving 192.* ip address. Also my primary question is how to make the charles proxy to listen on the ip interface of my choice instead of picking a default. Configure my mobile devices to specific ips is not always suitable for my development requitements

Comment: You've install certificate then set proxy to your wifi in your mobile

Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZItYzzs1psw

Comment: it has nothing to do with the certificate. All the certificates are installed correctly. My device connects to charles proxy running on other laptops having a single ip address. Only with laptops having two ip addresses it does not connect. You may need to read the question in detail. I don't get the basic connection prompt itself from CharleProxy. The requests made by a debive on 192.* n\w are not even reaching the proxy runnin on 10.* ip

Comment: Before you used Charles in your mobile or Is it first time

Comment: I have been using Charles Proxy + doing mobile development for 15 years now.

Comment: in either case, the proxy not connecting is due to the corporate firewall blocking the inbound connections. https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/access-control/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that changing the metric order of the nw interface allows charles to pick up the desired interface. Also, the corporate firewalls were blocking the inbound proxy connection requests on port 8888.

The following command on windows showed me the open ports and I used one of the open ports to configure Charles and now its working as expected and allowing Android\iOS devices to connect.

```
c:> netsh firewall show state
```